# Multiseasonal models for multivariate time series

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, multiple-seasonalities

Does there exist model (ideally implemented in R) which take into account multiseasonality for multivariate time series as BATS does in the univariate case?

Comment: It's very frustrating to see on this site that people can downvote questions which are well-posed and clear without any explanation.

Comment: It is a fine question.  Some on this site want only high-level, theoretical questions.  Others, myself included, enjoy niche questions like this (which can be used by Google-searchers in the future).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a possible answer for you at [this link](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/seasonal-periods/), which could provide you with more information on the specific package you are looking for.  According to the author, you may want to look into `msts` as a package for handling your type of data:

> An alternative is to use a `msts` object (defined in the `forecast` package) which handles multiple seasonality time series. Then you can specify all the frequencies that might be relevant. It is also flexible enough to handle non-integer frequencies.

As an example, below is an example on how to handle multiseasonality, using `taylor` electricity dataset (from `forcast` package) with daily ($24 \times 2$) and weekly ($24 \times 2 \times 7$) cycles:

```
x <- msts(taylor, seasonal.periods=c(24*2,24*2*7)) 
fit <- tbats(x[1:1000]) 
plot(forecast(fit))
```

Additionally, in case you may want to use dummy variables as @TomWitten suggests, you can view the information on [this page](https://petolau.github.io/Forecast-double-seasonal-time-series-with-multiple-linear-regression-in-R/), which deals with forecasting double (or multiple) seasonal multivariate time series, with specific examples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (I upvoted it). In fact, although `msts` objects can handle multivariate time series, that's not the case for `bats` and `tbats` so my problem isn't completely solved (except if using multiple linear regression with dummies as explained in the 2nd link you gave).

Answer (score 1):

if you know the seasonality could you not just create a series of dummy variables to capture the effects? In my time series data i had 12 monthly dummies for example

Comment: That's true of course but that doesn't really answer my question. Thank you (+1).